# Fortran: pipe to program

Tags: fortran, fortran90, gfortran

Is there any possibility to launch an external program from Fortran and write something to this programs standard input?

I know e.g. of gfortran's SYSTEM but there is no such option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, if you're using a relatively recent compiler you should be able to use `execute_command_line` (part of the f2008 spec) instead of `system` (compiler extension). This launches a command using the `C` library's `system` call which uses the `sh` shell on nix and `cmd.exe` on Windows (see [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/EXECUTE_005fCOMMAND_005fLINE.html)). As such you can use standard input redirection type approaches to connect to `stdin` of the launched program, but it may not be suitable for more complicated use.

The following example shows a simple example

```
program stdIn
  implicit none
  character(len=20) :: cmd, args
  character(len=50) :: fullcmd
  cmd = "bc"
  args = "1+2"
  fullcmd = cmd//" <<< "//args
  print*,"Running ",fullcmd
  call execute_command_line(fullcmd)
end program stdIn
```

Which should output

```
 Running bc                   <<< 1+2
 3
```

Comment: Thank you! But this way I have to construct the string first, which seems impractical, because I have a rather big  amount of data (I want to pipe results to gnuplot without havind to write a data file, because this is a huge slow-down).

Comment: Depending on how large your data is this may still be possible if you programmatically construct the string from your data, although it may not be very efficient/sensible. You may want to look at creating a ramdisk and then writing the data from fortran to this area. This should hopefully be fast and allow you to then just call `gnuplot` on the ram file.

Comment: A ramdisk is a good idea ... but I switched to Python for plotting as there I can use f2py and then call the Fortran code from python.

Comment: python is a more versatile option than gnuplot.

Answer (score 3):

As you have noticed, GFortran does not have anything like the pipe()/fork()/exec() functions builtin.

If you're on Linux or some other Unix-like system you could do something like

1. execute_command_line("mkfifo /path/to/fifo")

The mkfifo command creates a *named pipe*, that is, a pipe that also has a name in the filesystem.

2. open(newunit=plot_unit, file="/path/to/fifo", access="stream", format="formatted")
3. execute_command_line("gnuplot < /path/to/fifo")

So the idea is that you can then open the FIFO like a normal external unit in GFortran, then execute gnuplot with standard input connected to the FIFO.

You might need to exchange the order of #2 and #3 in case this deadlocks. But some minor variation of the above should work (I've used it to connect to one Fortran program from another).