# How to improve efficiency of a Fortran to Fortran operation?

Tags: performance, visual-studio-code, fortran

I have two Intel Fortran Projects A and B running parallel on Visual Studio 2010, Windows 10. The goal is to achieve the data transmission from Project A to Project B for each time step.

The logic is like this: at the current time step N, Project A creates the data transmission file “dataintoB.dat”. From the side of Project B, it opens and reads “dataintoB.dat”. Meanwhile, Project A should wait for Project B to finish opening and reading “dataintoB.dat” before proceeding to the next time step N+1.

To notice Project A that the opening and reading process by Project B is complete and continue running, the following method is taken, which includes creating a “dataintoA.dat” file by Project B:

```
open(1, file = 'dataintoA.dat', form = 'formatted')    % created by Project B 
   write(1,*) 1    % a random number is used
close(1)
```

and checking the existence of the file by Project A:

```
INQUIRE (FILE = "dataintoA.dat", EXIST = exists)   
if (.NOT. exists) then
    call sleep(30)     % assume 30 seconds is needed
end if
```

However, the above method is not efficient considering the 30 seconds sleep time in Project A for each time step. Is there any other method to improve the efficiency of this operation, such as a 'wait' instruction? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason they have to be separate processes? If you can change the code why can't A just call B as a subroutine? Alternatively you might look into the execute_command_line to start B within A every time you need it.But that just feels so ugly I can't bring myself to write an answer recommending it.

Comment: How much freedom do you have to change each of the programs? As with Ian Bush's comment, there can be several ways to change how processes talk to each other (or simply being changed to a single process), and another simple way could be sending a signal which says "hey, I've updated that file you are waiting for". Or what in POSIXland would be pipes/sockets. But suggestions depend on other structure and what changes you can make.

Comment: @IanBush, these two programs are independent of each other and cannot be merged into a single process.

Comment: @francescalus, these two programs are independent and cannot be changed into a single process. Can you provide more details for your method?

Comment: Yes you can, if you have the source code and if you have the time and the appropriate knowledge. What is not clear is whether you have the source code, or if you have the time and knowledge to do such work.  Please clarify.

Comment: @IanBush, unfortunately, I have the source code but no time

Comment: I'm afraid if you can't change the code you may well be stuck with what you have

Comment: For more info about francescalus' suggestion, these pages might be useful (e.g. for named pipes) https://cyber.dabamos.de/programming/modernfortran/inter-process-communication.html https://www.networkworld.com/article/3251853/why-use-named-pipes-on-linux.html http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37763832/fortran-pipe-to-program/37776740#37776740